# ScalaMock : expect a Double within some tolerance

Tags: scala, scalamock

I am using a `MockFunction1`, expecting an argument and expecting it to be called once.

```
mockFunction.expects(result).once()
```

The type of `result` object contains several values of type Double.

I want the expected `result` object to match the actual within some tolerance limits. (For example, if the actual object contains a value 10.742345, I want the expected object with value 10.74 to match).

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
The type of `result` object is of the form:

```
class Result {
 ...
  m: Metrics,
 ...
}
class Metrics {
 ...
  a: Double,
  b: Double,
 ...

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the result method?

Comment: @AmitPrasad The `result` above is not a method. It's an object which internally contains several values of type Double.

Comment: okay, then you might do like `result - (result % 0.01)` for two decimal precision.

Comment: @AmitPrasad I have updated the question with the form the `result` object can take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears there is no built in mechanism in scalamock to give a default comparator for comparing all instances of a type.

To work around this, I ended up using 'argument capture' and writing a custom comparator for the entire object:

```
val actualResult = CaptureOne[Result]()
mockFunction expects capture(actualResult) once
....
actualResult.value.shouldEqual(result)(EqualityWithTolerance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `where` as custom matcher:

```scala
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalamock.function.FunctionAdapter1

case class Foo(d: Double, otherField: String)

trait Service {
  def f(p: Foo): String = s"call f on $p"
}

// add function to construct custom matchers:
def toTolerantMatcher(expected: Foo): FunctionAdapter1[Foo, Boolean] =
  where {
    (actual: Foo) => (~expected.d).equals(actual.d) && expected.otherField == actual.otherField
  }

// and use it in your test:
val service = mock[Service]
val expected = Foo(0.0004, "example")
(service.f _).expects(toTolerantMatcher(expected)).once()
val actual = Foo(0.0003, "example")
service.f(actual)
```

inside `toTolarantMatcher` unary operator `~` makes comparing `d` field with tolerance (from `org.scalamock.matchers`):

```scala
object MatchEpsilon {

  val epsilon = 0.001
}
```